# How to aggregate column of vectors in Pandas after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that has users with features (calculated from TensorFlow word embeddings). I want to be able to group by user and calculate either a mean or median of the vectorized features:

> embeddings

```
user    features
bob [-0.030460168, -0.0014596573, 0.0997446, -0.18...
bob [-0.03197706, 0.015620711, 0.05890667, -0.0402...
bob [-0.060918115, 0.07939958, 0.0333591, 0.035655...
mary    [-0.012854534, 0.07733478, 0.12939823, 0.00992...
mary    [-0.04184026, 0.03382166, 0.1427004, -0.204424...
```

I tried something like this:

```
df.groupby('user').agg(count=('user', lambda x: len(x)),
                       mean=('features', lambda x: np.mean(x)))
```

But it raises the following error:

```
Exception: Must produce aggregated value
```

Comment: What is exactly in one cell of the features?

Comment: As far as I can tell each cell is a floating point.

Comment: Try `agg({'user': lambda x: len(x), 'features' : lambda x : np.mean(x)})`

Comment: @DanielMesejo That produces the same error.

Comment: You can use `groupby().apply()` and write a custom function that takes the mean of the list in the `features` column. Can you give me a reproducible sample of about 10 rows? You can just convert first 10 rows to a list and paste it in your question.

Comment: What does np.mean(x) returns?

Comment: I dont think you can use `lambda x: len(x)` for this.

Comment: `df.groupby('user').apply(lambda x: sum(x['features']/len(x)))` works but it results in an unnamed column.

Comment: What is the type of features?

Comment: @DanielMesejo numpy.ndarray of float32 values

Comment: Is this `EPO6NDP8XR63XD94L1` part of features?

Comment: @DanielMesejo No that is the user id ('user' column)

Comment: consider `df.explode()` if you are using pandas 0.25+

Comment: Also, I would reconsider construction of the dataframe in question. If it is possible, build the dataframe like `name, feature0, feature1, ...`

Comment: @QuangHoang Why? It's quite tedious to work with 500 columns unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: It's generally advised not to put list/array/e.t.c inside dataframes. `sklearn`, for example, also designed to work with each column as a single feature. On the one hand, it allows for more efficient memory management. On the other hand, it helps you analyze the features independently, or (partially) jointly, at ease. And it's obvious from your use case, it allows calculation of aggregation in one pass.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks for the advice. For now I want to solve this problem with lists/arrays, if possible. If it's not possible, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `x` is a pd.Series of numpy.arrays, assuming you want the centroid, you could use [np.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) and find the mean accross the first axis:

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arrays = [np.array([-0.030460168, -0.0014596573, 0.0997446, -0.18]),
          np.array([-0.03197706, 0.015620711, 0.05890667, -0.0402]),
          np.array([-0.060918115, 0.07939958, 0.0333591, 0.035655]),
          np.array([-0.012854534, 0.07733478, 0.12939823, 0.00992]),
          np.array([-0.04184026, 0.03382166, 0.1427004, -0.204424])]

users = ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'mary', 'mary']

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'user': users, 'features': arrays})
```

**Code**

```
result = df.groupby('user').agg(count=('user', lambda x: len(x)),
                       mean=('features', lambda x: np.vstack(x).mean(axis=0).tolist()))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
      count                                               mean
user                                                          
bob       3  [-0.04111844766666667, 0.031186877899999996, 0...
mary      2  [-0.027347397, 0.055578220000000005, 0.1360493...
```

Comment: I would have been banging my head for a while trying to figure out to put vstack in there, although I do remember now having to do something similar in the past, so it made sense right away. :)